# eTarget.id.style.display = 'none' not working

Tags: javascript

I wanted to hide this div on click using the script that follows the HTML code but it doesn't seem to work though adding alert(eTarget.id) in between the code returns the div id specsC. If I simply replace event.id with specsC in the script, it works fine.

```
<div class = 'tile1c' id='specsC' onclick='hide()'>
    <h3>Specifications</h3>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function hide(e){
    if(!e)
        e = window.event;
    eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;
    eTarget.id.style.display = 'none';
    }
<script>
```

Comment: Erm... remove `.id`, problem solved!

Comment: Seriously, why are you trying to set the display of the style of the *id* of the element? XD

Comment: I'm a beginner :-p I get it now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just:

```
eTarget.style.display = 'none';
```

`id` should not be there.

`eTarget.id` resolves to the string `"specsC"`.